# No puedo instalar nginx por dependencias incumplidas

Tags: nginx

Ejecuté los comandos en este orden:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Me dió este error:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 nginx : Depende: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.15.8-8.6.0.2~trusty1) pero no va a instalarse
         Depende: nginx-extras (< 1:1.15.8-8.6.0.2~trusty1.1~) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Acto seguido ejecuté estos comandos:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nginx*
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Y me da exactamente el mismo error al tratar de instalar nginx.

Pruebo con esto:

```
$ sudo apt install nginx-extras
```

Y me genera este error:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 nginx-extras : Depende: nginx-common (= 1:1.12.2-8.5.1.12~trusty1) pero 1:1.15.8-8.6.0.2~trusty1 va a ser instalado
                Depende: perlapi-5.18.2 pero no es instalable
                Depende: libperl5.18 (>= 5.18.2) pero no es instalable
                Recomienda: passenger (>= 5.1.12) pero no va a instalarse
                Recomienda: passenger (< 5.1.13) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Y se me trancó el serrucho.

¿alguna idea que pueda ser?

**ACTUALIZACION:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: mira en `/etc/apt/sources.list` si tienes esta línea y que no esté comentada con `#`:  `deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx`.

Comment: El problema era que tenia en ese archivo **/etc/apt/sources.list** esta linea *deb oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main* que ya comenté y pude instalar nginx

Comment: Bien! parece que hay un problema conocido en ubuntu 18.. https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2122